Overriding a variable assigned to an evaluated method in the parent class using a child class
I am new to object oriented programming. I have a parent class in whose constructor I have a variable (bmi in the below example) that requires a method (bod_mass_idx) of the same class to be evaluated (I do this because this method takes time to evaluate and is used multiple times by later methods in the same class, so I don't want to compute it each time I want to use it).
I am trying to construct a child class that overrides the variable that stores the expensive-to-calculate method that I define in my parent class. Of course, my actual example is a lot more complex than this, but this example summarizes the essential details.
class Human:
    def __init__(self, height, weight):
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        self.prefactor = 1.0
        self.bmi = self.bod_mass_idx()
        
    def bod_mass_idx(self):
        return self.prefactor * self.weight/self.height**2
    
class MetaHuman(Human):
    def __init__(self, height, weight, fraction):
        super().__init__(height, weight)
        self.prefactor = fraction

Here, I want the value fraction defined in MetaHuman to replace the prefactor in Human. But when I initialize the child class and try to evaluate the bmi method, I do not get an updated value :
hum = Human(2,100)
m_hum = MetaHuman(2,100,0.5)

print(m_hum.bmi()) #25.0
print(hum.bmi()) #25.0

but calling the method gives me the expected values :
print(m_hum.bod_mass_idx()) #12.5
print(hum.bod_mass_idx()) #25.0


Why does the object behave in this manner?
What would be a workaround for this situation?

In my case, the parent class helps set up a simulation with certain "base" conditions, and the child class adds certain quirks to the simulation. I felt it would be nice to not reuse code to write a new simulation and decided to use OOP :)
P.S. I am new to object oriented programming, and am still working my way through the lingo.

bmi is computed once, in Human.__init__, using the hard-coded value of 1.0 before MetaHuman.__init__ changes the value to fraction. Since its value depends on values that could change (height, weight, or prefactor), it would be better to compute it on demand, rather than storing it as an attribute.
class Human:
    def __init__(self, height, weight):
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        self.prefactor = 1.0

    @property
    def bmi(self):
        return self.prefactor * self.weight/self.height**2
    
class MetaHuman(Human):
    def __init__(self, height, weight, fraction):
        super().__init__(height, weight)
        self.prefactor = fraction


There are all sorts of issues surrounding the idea of an instance attribute being fixed for all instances of a class. Depending on how you plan on using prefector, neither Human as a subclass of MetaHuman nor MetaHuman as a subclass of Human may be appropriate.

What's happening is that during your super().__init__(height,weight) calculation, the self.bmi is already calculated before the self.prefactor can be reassigned from 1.0 to fraction.
In the second example, calling the bod_mass_idx() method displays the correct value because its performing the calculation for m_hum a second time after self-prefactor has been updated.
One way to get around this would be to call the bod_mass_idx() during the MetaHuman init.
class MetaHuman(Human):
    def __init__(self, height, weight, fraction):
        super().__init__(height, weight)
        self.prefactor = fraction
        self.bmi = self.bod_mass_idx()


to call bod_mass_idx() only once whether it's for Human or MetaHuman, maybe you can do it this way.
There are other solutions, I don't know which is best.
class Human:
    def __init__(self, height, weight):
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        self.prefactor = getattr(self, 'prefactor', 1.0)  # Default to 1.0 if not set
        self.bmi = self.bod_mass_idx()
        
    def bod_mass_idx(self):
        return self.prefactor * self.weight/self.height**2
    
class MetaHuman(Human):
    def __init__(self, height, weight, fraction):
        self.prefactor = fraction
        super().__init__(height, weight)

So in MetaHuman, define prefactor before calling super().init. And in Human, only set the prefactor to 1 if it doesn't already have a value.
